# On which versions of SQL Server can I use VARCHAR(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server, max

On which versions of SQL Server can I use `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

From experimentation I can't use it on 2000, but I can use it on 2008 R2, but where was it introduced in between these two versions?

Comment: [All supported versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?C2=1044&forceorigin=esmc)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a relevant question, even if not you the serial downvoter.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK since SQL Server 2005 where NTEXT was deprecated and NVARCHAR goes in. More info [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsperfblog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) and [here](http://www.teratrax.com/sql-server-data-types-ranges/).

**EDIT**

Same goes to VARCHAR.

> Microsoft introduced the VARCHAR(MAX),  NVARCHAR(MAX), and VARBINARY(MAX) data types in SQL Server 2005.